# Include a JavaScript file as it was written in a script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have some html, that had a bunch of JS code inside a script tag. So I moved it to a separate .js file.

JS code also loaded some variables from CGI, using strings in a form of `<%ejGet(var)%>`. But after separating the code from HTML file, the strings don't get replaced with data from the server.

Is there a way to include a JS file as if it was written inside a script tag or is there another way to do this?

```
<script language="javascript">
<!-- hide
var syncNvram = '<%ejGetWl(wlSyncNvram)%>';
...about 1000 lines more...
</script>
```

So after moving this code to a separate file, the variables don't load.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: I've edited my question...but there is a lot of code, and I don't think it will really help much

Comment: try `<%=ejGetWl(wlSyncNvram)%>`

Comment: Variable declaration would have to remain within your template file, just make sure the js file using it is included after it's been declared and you should be fine.

Comment: `language="javascript"` — Please don't write new code using HTML 3.2.

Comment: `<!-- hide` — Nobody uses Netscape 1 and its contemporaries any more. You don't need to take steps to hide scripts from browsers which don't recognise the script element.

Comment: @Quentin its a very old HTML

Comment: here is a post with solution about the same problem; the server side code is C#, but it's the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653331/passing-parameters-from-my-view-page-to-my-js-file/9653422#9653422

Comment: Why the downvote? This stackoverflow is getting really stupid. Don't know why am I still asking questions here, I would probably get answers on other sites from stackexchange network and wouldn't get downvoted...I don't even know what questions to ask here anymore.

Comment: @Tom this solution is not really related..sorry if I didn't ask my question properly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `<% ejGetWl(wlSyncNvram) %>` is being executed on the **server** by some templating or processing engine **before** it gets sent to the browser, so the browser is actually seeing the output, e.g.

var syncNvram = 'abcdefg'; // or whatever the output is

The question you are really asking is, can my server side templating/processing engine process a javascript file as opposed to an html file.

The answer is, it depends on the template/processing engine, but in general, this is a bad idea. JS files should remain static assets for lots of good reasons (breaking code, distributing via CDNs, etc.)

The better thing to do is separate them out:

```
<script>var syncNvram = '<%ejGetWl(wlSyncNvram)%>';</script>
<script src="myfile.js"></script>
```

Declare it separately.

Even better might be using ajax to get it, but that is a whole different architecture which may not suit here.

Answer (score -1):

To do that you need to generate the script from the CGI program.

```
<script src="/cgi-bin/example.js.cgi"></script>
```

Of course, that will be a *different* CGI program so getting the variables in the right state may be problematic.

Usually you would solve the problem using a different approach: include the data in the document (either in the script element or in an element such as a `<meta>` element, a hidden input or a `data-*` attribute on something relevant and then have a static script read the data from the DOM.